# How to return something if Python re.findall() finds something without using else statement?

Tags: python, python-re

I want to use `if` and `elif` conditions to check if `re.findall()` was able to find characters in an input without using `else`. Is it possible?

Here's what I've tried:

```py
import re

a = input('')

txt = '[a-zA-Z0!@]'

search = re.findall(txt, a)

if len(search) == 0:
    print('nothing')

elif len(search) == 1:  # assuming that the user input contains many numbers of characters, it's
    print('ok')         # impossible to guess how many characters len(search) will be equal to..
```

If the user input exceeds 1 character, the elif statement gets ignored. What should I  do?

Comment: You want your elif block to execute if `len(search)` is greater than or equal to 1, like `elif len(search) >= 1:`, is that right? That would essentially be the same as just using an `else`, what do you have against using one?

Comment: What about `elif len(search) == len(a):`

Answer (score 0):

This is hugely contrived and not recommended because if/else is going to be more readable/understandable. But to answer the question as asked:

```
import re
d = {True: 'ok', False: 'nothing'}
ui = input('Type something: ')
t = re.findall('[a-zA-Z0!@]', ui)
print(d[bool(t)])
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `bool`:

```
bool(search)
```

example:

```
bool(re.findall('[a-zA-Z0!@]', 'abc'))
True

bool(re.findall('[a-zA-Z0!@]', ''))
False
```

Comment: maybe I didn't get the question correctly, is there anything wrong here?